Hit noise when playing part of wave file with ALSA PCM interface
I am working a WAVE file playing with ALSA PCM interface in Linux, and I heard noise when I played the file quickly and partially.
Here is my playing function.
static int playback_function(uint8_t *pcm_buf, int pcm_frames)
{
    int  rc;
    uint8_t *buf;
    int frame_size, sent;
    int periodsize;
    int left;

    frame_size = chan * av_get_bytes_per_sample(AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16);
    periodsize = sys_periodsize; // 320 in my system
    buf = pcm_buf;
    left = pcm_frames;
    sent = 0;

    while (left > 0) {
        sent = (left > periodsize) ? periodsize : left;
        rc = snd_pcm_writei(pcm_handle, buf, sent);
        printf("rc: %d, sent: %d\n", rc, sent);
        if (rc == -EAGAIN || (rc >= 0 && (size_t)rc < sent)) {
            snd_pcm_wait(pcm_handle, 10);
        } else if (rc == -EPIPE) {
            snd_pcm_recover(pcm_handle, rc, 0);
        } else if (rc < 0) {
            break;
        }
        if (rc > 0) {
            left -= rc;
            buf += rc * frame_size;
        }
    }
    return rc;
}

The pcm_buf and pcm_frames are got from swr_convert() in libswresample, in my case, the pcm_frames is 1187.
By adding printf("rc: %d, sent: %d\n", rc, sent);, I got following logs.
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 87, sent: 87
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 103, sent: 103
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 103, sent: 103
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 103, sent: 103
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 103, sent: 103
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 103, sent: 103
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 103, sent: 103
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 103, sent: 103
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 103, sent: 103
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 87, sent: 87
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 320, sent: 320
rc: 103, sent: 103

With above function, sometimes I can hear noise when playing the WAVE file quickly and repeatly.
So, how can I improve the WAVE playing without the noise??
I changed the above function by filling 0 to the end of data buffer (to enforce silence).
static int playback_test(uint8_t *pcm_buf, int pcm_frames)
{
    uint8_t *buf;
    int trd;
    int rc;
    int left;
    int frame_size, sent;
    int periodsize;
    int aligned = 0;

    frame_size = chan * av_get_bytes_per_sample(AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16);
    periodsize = sys_periodsize; // 320 in my system

    buf = pcm_buf;
    left = pcm_frames;
    aligned = (left/periodsize + 1) * periodsize;
    memset(buf + left * frame_size, 0, (aligned - left) * frame_size);
    sent = 0;
///left = periodsize; // <== This causes more noise!!

    while (left > 0) {
        sent = (left > periodsize) ? periodsize : left;
        rc = snd_pcm_writei(pcm_handle, buf, sent);
        printf("rc: %d, sent: %d\n", rc, sent);
        if (rc == -EAGAIN || (rc >= 0 && (size_t)rc < sent)) {
            snd_pcm_wait(pcm_handle, 10);
        } else if (rc == -EPIPE) {
            snd_pcm_recover(pcm_handle, rc, 0);
        } else if (rc < 0) {
            break;
        }
        if (rc > 0) {
            left -= rc;
            buf += rc * frame_size;
        }
    }
    return rc;
}

There is NO improvement as of the noise.

@CL. would you please help reviewing the codes and shining your light on it?
